# ApI AI app works fine on web simulator but not on Android phone

Tags: android, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-home, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to create an api.ai based app on Google home. Tested using the web simulator and Google Home, it works completely fine. Application is just in dev mode, not yet send to Google to approve.

Now, I tried to test this app from my Android Phone - I think, that I should do it from Google App, but when I said "Ok, Google, talk to " - it just search this utterance, without any real interaction.

What I am doing wrong, how it should really work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work, just double check the below points

1. Make sure that you are using same Google account in action.google console and in your android phone.
2. You said, you are trying to invoke it from google home app. Up to my knowledge it won't work from google app, you have to invoke it from google assistance.
3. Check if your phone has google assistance enabled, to do that : long press on your home button. If you already have it, then just say Talk to my test app.

let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're activating Google Search, not Google Assistant. Press and hold the home button on your Android device running Marshmallow or later to activate Google Assistant.

There's more information available on the [Google Support](https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/7172657) website.