# actions on google demo code is not working on my android phone

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I followed https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/first-app tutorial and built my first google action. The action is working fine on my laptop browser in the test (Followed "Preview the App" section of the tutorial) environment. However, when I am trying to use this action on my phone by saying "OK Google talk to my first app". It's not working. Is it supposed to work on my phone as well? I have logged in with the same Gmail account on my phone also.

PS - I have posted the same question on "actions on google" google plus community google as well but I am not sure if that community is to post such questions or not. Therefore, I am posting it here also.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have already verified the steps mentioned in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45862225/api-ai-app-works-fine-on-web-simulator-but-not-on-android-phone

Comment: I think testing on android phone is not supported at the moment

Comment: Its supported. The issue was my phone memory was only 1 GB. Google assistant needs at least 1.5 GB to work.

Comment: now working on my device too. language issues...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have enabled testing through the simulator, it should be available on all devices (mobile, speakers like Google Home, etc) with the same account your simulator is running in. Double check to make sure they're the same account.

In your case, however, you may be using the wrong invocation phrase. If you actually said what you did above, you need to say the *exact same thing* that you typed to invoke it.

If you haven't set a name in the configuration, then that phrase will be

- Talk to my **test** app

**Update**

As you note in the comments - you also need to make sure you're running the *Google Assistant*, and not one of the other voice search components. The Google Assistant [requires](https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/7172657):

- Android 6.0 or higher
- Google app 6.13 or higher
- Google Play services
- 1.5 GB of memory
- 720p screen resolution
- Phone set to a supported language

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I am using the phrase "talk to my test app" on my phone as well as on the simulator. It's working fine on the simulator but the phone.  Earlier I have verified it again both (Simulator and mobile) are using the same account. However, I have a few more Gmail accounts added to my Gmail. I believe this will not cause any issue as my active account is same. When I say "talk to my test app" on my phone, google assistant speak back with "Here is a summary on GitHub......". screenshots are here: https://imgur.com/a/jGr40

Comment: I think I am its google voice search, not the assistant. My phone doesn't have 1.5 GB of RAM and that's the reason I am not getting google assistant on my phone.

Comment: I just bought a new phone and it's working fine now. The issue was my older phone has < 1.5 GB RAM. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I was going to say that that didn't look like the Assistant. Glad you figured out the problem and that it's working for you now.

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably already know you have to enable Web & App Activity, Device Information, Voice & Audio Activity in the Activity controls page.

Then you also have to be sure that the language of your agent is the same used by your google assistant.

I solved thanks this last step.

Hope this helps